# Creating a Generic Dictionary in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to create a Generic type that represents a dictionary. Something like this:

```
export type Dictionary<K extends string | number, V> = {[k: K]: V};
```

Even though I've limited the type to string | number, I still get an error saying "An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.".
Is there any way to achieve this in Typescript?

Comment: mb will suit you `Record<string | number, number>`? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) is handy for these kind of situations:

```js
export type Dictionary<K extends string | number, V> = Record<K, V>;
```